# Unable to find Namespace for SPWeb, SPUser or SPControl, Provider-Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin

Using a Provider Hosted Application for SharePoint 2013, I am unable to ue the following lines in my C# code to get the current user

```
SPWeb web = SPControl.GetContextWeb(this.Context);
SPUser sUser = web.CurrentUser;
```

The error is that it says I am unable to find namespace.

I tried to add the following to the top of the page, but WebControls does not exist.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
```

Any ideas of what I'm misisng?

thanks!
Graham.

Comment: Start with using Microsoft.SharePoint

Comment: I am, I have that one declared as well, right above this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to figure this out.

I was calling the wrong classes.  Web and User where the ones i needed, not SPUser and SPWeb.

I also needed to execute the query to fill up web and current user.  Here is a snippit of my code to create a dictionary of some variables.

```
using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithContextToken(hostWeb, contextToken, Request.Url.Authority)) {
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            User currentUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser;

            clientContext.Load(web);  //, web => web.Title);
            clientContext.Load(currentUser);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            //get timestamp
            string ts = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");

            Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dictionary.Add("name", currentUser.Title);
            dictionary.Add("email", currentUser.Email);
            dictionary.Add("timestamp", ts);
}
```

With this code, I am also able to grab content from the 'web' variable.